# How to get a TEXT response from an IBM serverless function?

Tags: ibm-cloud, restful-url, serverless, openwhisk

I want to use a serverless Function to generate (and expose via a URL) a CSV-like output.
From the [documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/openwhisk_apigateway.html#openwhisk_apigateway) I understand 
that this could be achieved using the tag `--response-type text`. However I am not succedding at it.

My code is this hello.py script

```
def main(args):
    text = '1,2,3'
    # json = {'a': [1,2,3]}
    response = text
    return response
```

(Please note the use the variables `text` or `json` to return the proper format, depending on the `--response-type` tag used to generate the Function.)

I am building the Function as follows:

```
ibmcloud wsk action delete hello
ibmcloud wsk action create hello hello.py --web true
ibmcloud wsk api create /hello get hello --response-type text
```

From where I obtain a URL: 
`https://service.us.apiconnect.ibmcloud.com/gws/apigateway/api/<GENERATED_API_ID>/hello`

But once I hit the URL I get an error:

```
{
  "error": "There was an error processing your request.",
  "code": "35976969ecfff22ab15b274a5a56e45b"
}
```

If instead, I return a json from the Function, and create the Function using `--response-type json`, then
everything works as expected and I get the beautiful JSON on the browser.

Does anyone has an idea what may be going on?

Note 1: The response will be captured by a service that won't allow (easy) processing of the JSON, and 
from there my need of the CSV format.

Note 2: I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow%20.com/questions/41678754/ibm-bus-rest-api-text-responce) for a very similar topic, and a potential solution. However I do not see how to implement it or use it in my case.

Thank you all in advance,

Manuel

Answer (score 3):

The function must always return a JSON object (python dictionary). If you are exposing the function as an API end point, namely an openwhisk web action, then you can return the following response: `return { body: text }`

Refer to the docs here for more details https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/blob/master/docs/webactions.md

Comment: Any idea then what is the purpose of `--response-type TEXT` then? Thank you for replying.

Comment: The --response-type flag controls the target URL of the web action to be proxied by the API Gateway. For example, when you use the --response-type text flag, the full result of the action is returned in TEXT format and the webaction url has a .text appended to it. See content extensions here https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/blob/master/docs/webactions.md#content-extensions.